# I recently changed my hosting and now I can only send emails and not receive using GMail

Tags: email, domain, hosting, mx-record, gmail

I have a domain name (emmasteed.co.uk) that I have hosted with UK Reg and I recently moved my hosting to GoDaddy. I have an email that I have used for a few years now: emma@emmasteed.co.uk. When I changed my hosting I set up this email address again in GMail and put in the new username, password etc. into my GMail settings so that I am able to send and receive emails from this account. This has worked before but since setting this up I have only been able to send emails but not receive.

I have used the settings that GoDaddy have sent me. I spoke to someone at support at GoDaddy and they said that I need to change my MX records to Google's. Which I thought was odd as I never needed to do this before but I did so anyway and it has made no difference. I am only using GMail on my desktop to access my emails. I made these changes 5 days ago so there has been plenty of time for it to complete.

I was reinserting the same settings over and over in my GMail account yesterday and for a moment it acually worked and I started to receive emails but then it stopped working again.

The server settings I am using:

```
SMTP: n1plcpnl0058.prod.ams1.secureserver.net Port: 495
POP:  n1plcpnl0058.prod.ams1.secureserver.net Port: 995
```

- I am only able to enter these settings if I have this option selected: 'Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail.' If I don't have this checked it just times out when trying to connect.

I have been going through so many forums with this issue and have not come across any answers. Is there something that I am potentially missing?

Answer (score 1):

The MX records tell other people where to send email for emmasteed.co.uk.

The above POP settings tell your mail client where the server is that it should get your mail from.  Google also handles the IMAP protocolo which does a similar thing.

The SMTP setting tells your mail client which server it should contact to send mail through.

Unfortunately, at the moment everyone is sending your mail to Google and you're trying to retrieve it from GoDaddy.

If you want Google to handle your mail, you should find the POP, IMAP and SMTP settings for Gmail and enter those into your mail client instead of the `secureserver.net` domains.  If you want GoDaddy to handle your mail, you should change your MX records back to GoDaddy's.

---

Gmail *can* send emails claiming to be `From: emma@emmasteed.co.uk` (in fact, anyone can) but other factors such as SPF, DKIM and DMARC can get in the way of these actually being delivered.  This is to prevent other people pretending to be you.

You do have an SPF record and it's currently set to only allow GoDaddy's servers to send mail from emmasteed.co.uk.  I can't tell if you have DKIM or DMARC.  If you choose to go with Gmail, you will have to change that SPF record as well.

Comment: Thank you for getting in touch. Ok, so because I have changed my MX records to point to Google I need to change the server settings? I am not really sure which way round I would like to do it. Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault. There are a couple of things that you might want to check. Who is providing your email service? Is it still with UK Reg or has that been moved to GoDaddy?

If it is still with UK Reg you will need to amend your MX records in the DNS settings at GoDaddy to point to the UK Reg email server.

It is also entirely possible that you have completely cancelled your email and hosting with UK Reg, in which case you would need to open a new email account with GoDaddy and amend the MX records to point to the GoDaddy email server.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond I really appreciate that. However I have never had my hosting with UK Reg it was with someone else. I just have my domain name registered at UK Reg.

Comment: Then your email hosting is probably with that other party. You will need to get their server address in your MX record.